# Элемент WebView не отображает страницы HTTP

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Страницы с протоколом https он грузит, а http - нет. В манифесте я добавил разрешение на интернет. Пытаюся загрузить страницу http://b98300b7.beget.tech/ но в приложении пишет, что не удалось загрузить сраницу. Программирую на Java.

Comment: Добавьте в манифесте в application вот это: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: Возникла проблема, сайт открывается в браузере а не в приложении. Как исправить?

Comment: Уже разобрался. Спасибо за android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в манифесте в application вот это:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Еще раз спасибо

Comment: А как Вы сделали серый фон в коменте и в ответе?

Comment: Для этого надо или 4 пробела отступа сделать или косыми апострофа и окружить или в редакторе кода кнопочку нажать с фигурными скобками, выделив нужный текст. По сути - стандартная фича `Markdown`

Comment: `Понял, спасибо!`